# A more elegant way to use the result of multiple callbacks in a function?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, callback

I'm still somewhat new to asynchronous programming and I've been wondering if there's a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do.

```
exports.content = function(req, res){
  OPID = req.params.id;

  titles.findOne({postID: OPID}, function (err, post) { //function #1
    if (err) throw(err); 

    readComment(OPID, function(comment){ //function #2

      branchFilter.getBranches(function(branches){ //function #3

        res.render('content', {title: post.title, content: post.body, OPID: post.postID, comments: comment, branches: branches});
      })
    });
  });
};
```

In this example I have three nested function which use callbacks to retrieve data from other modules. I need to have all this data in the res.render statement. I imagine if I continue with this approach I'm going to need even more nested functions. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: [Promises](https://github.com/kriskowal/q).

Comment: https://github.com/caolan/async

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As JohnnyHK suggested, a good async library will help you out with this.  I would also suggest [Caolan's async](https://github.com/caolan/async).  You can get around pretty much any asynchronous problem with a combination of `auto` and `forEach`, although if runtime is an issue `async` may not be the best choice.  I would rewrite your code as follows:

```
exports.content = function(req, res){
  OPID = req.params.id;

  async.auto({
    post: function(next) {
      titles.findOne({postID: OPID}, next);
    },
    comment: function(next) {
      readComment(OPID, function(comment){ next(null, comment); });
    },
    branches: function(next) {
      branchFilter.getBranches(function(branches){ next(null, branches); });
    }
  }, function(err, results) {
    if(err) throw(err);
    res.render('content', {title: results.post.title, content: results.post.body, OPID: results.post.postID, comments: results.comment, branches: results.branches});
  });
};
```

What `auto` does is takes a dictionary of functions (with optional dependencies on other functions in the dictionary - see the async readme for more) and passes the results as a dictionary to the second argument, a "final" function.

If any of the functions passes a non-null `err` to its callback (the first argument), it stops calling other functions and immediately passes `err` and a `null` results to the "final" function.

Note how I had to pass anonymous functions in the `branches` and `comment` functions.  This is because `auto`, like the other functions in this `async` library, expects the first argument to its callback to be the error value and the second to be the results.

Answer (score 2):

For you example, have a function that just gets the data

```
exports.content = function(req, res){
   getData(req, function(err, data) { 
   // trivial error handling
   if (err) {
      console.dir('error getting your data', err);
      return res.redirect('/');
   }
   res.render('content', data)
}

// cb is a callback function
function getData(req, cb) {
  OPID = req.params.id;
  titles.findOne({postID: OPID}, function (err, post) { //function #1
    if (err) { return cb(err); }
    readComment(OPID, function(err, comment){ //function #2 (with error handling)
      if (err) { return cb(err); }
      branchFilter.getBranches(function(err, branches){ //function #3
        if (err) { return cb(err); }
        var output = {
          title: post.title, 
          content: post.body, 
          OPID: post.postID, 
          comments: comment, branches: branches
        }
        return cb(null, output);
      });
    });
  });
}
```

---

Take a look at http://callbackhell.com/ gives a very good overview on how write clean code using 
callbacks. The following is copied from that site

## Name Your Functions

Here is some (messy) browser javascript that uses browser-request to make an AJAX request to a server:

```
var form = document.querySelector('form')
form.onsubmit = function(submitEvent) {
  var name = document.querySelector('input').value
  request({
    uri: "http://example.com/upload",
    body: name,
    method: "POST"
  }, function(err, response, body) {
    var statusMessage = document.querySelector('.status')
    if (err) return statusMessage.value = err
    statusMessage.value = body
  })
}
```

This code has two anonymous functions. Let's give em names!

```
var form = document.querySelector('form')
form.onsubmit = function formSubmit(submitEvent) {
  var name = document.querySelector('input').value
  request({
    uri: "http://example.com/upload",
    body: name,
    method: "POST"
  }, function postResponse(err, response, body) {
    var statusMessage = document.querySelector('.status')
    if (err) return statusMessage.value = err
    statusMessage.value = body
  })
}
```

As you can see naming functions is super easy and does some nice things to your code:

- makes code easier to read
- when exceptions happen you will get stacktraces that reference actual function names instead of "anonymous"
- allows you to keep your code shallow, or not nested deeply, which brings me to my next point:

## Keep your code shallow

Building on the last example, let's go a bit further and get rid of the triple level nesting that is going on in the code:

```
function formSubmit(submitEvent) {
  var name = document.querySelector('input').value
  request({
    uri: "http://example.com/upload",
    body: name,
    method: "POST"
  }, postResponse)
}

function postResponse(err, response, body) {
  var statusMessage = document.querySelector('.status')
  if (err) return statusMessage.value = err
  statusMessage.value = body
}

document.querySelector('form').onsubmit = formSubmit
```

Code like this is less scary to look at and is easier to edit, refactor and hack on later.

## Modularize!

This is the most important part: Anyone is capable of creating modules (AKA libraries). To quote Isaac Schlueter (of the node.js project): "Write small modules that each do one thing, and assemble them into other modules that do a bigger thing. You can't get into callback hell if you don't go there."

Let's take out the boilerplate code from above and turn it into a module by splitting it up into a couple of files. Since I write JavaScript in both the browser and on the server, I'll show a method that works in both but is still nice and simple.

Here is a new file called formuploader.js that contains our two functions from before:

```
function formSubmit(submitEvent) {
  var name = document.querySelector('input').value
  request({
    uri: "http://example.com/upload",
    body: name,
    method: "POST"
  }, postResponse)
}

function postResponse(err, response, body) {
  var statusMessage = document.querySelector('.status')
  if (err) return statusMessage.value = err
  statusMessage.value = body
}

exports.submit = formSubmit
```

Comment: Excellent reference as http://callbackhell.com